# c# base key word outside constructor

Tags: c#

```
namespace ClientApp
{
    [Service(Exported = false)]
    class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        public RegistrationIntentService() :  base("RegistrationIntentService") { }
```

In the snippet above, the constructor extends a base("RegistrationIntentService"), what is this doing?
I found this example at: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/

Does it mean the contructor is the same as the `RegistrationIntentService` constructor?

Comment: This isn't Xamarin-specific - it's just C# syntax for calling the base class constructor. If you're new to C#, I'd strongly learn the basics of the language in a more conventional environment before you move on to mobile where there are extra constraints and oddities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just calling `IntentService`'s constructor with a string parameter `"RegistrationIntentService"`. It is a C# language keyword and is not Xamarin specific.

If the base class of an object does not have a default constructor, you must provide parameters to a base constructor in the derived class's constructor using this syntax.

See the [MSDN documentation on the base keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) for some examples.